# How to get an unlit textured view in Object Mode?

Tags: 3d-view

So I painted my texture in Texture Paint mode and I can see it all just fine. Now I go back to Object Mode and I can't see the texture. If I go from Solid to Texture view, I just see flat white object.

If I change the viewport display method to GLSL it goes to black, and then I add a light I can see the texture but this isn't what I want. I don't want/need Blender's lighting (it's just getting exported to a game engine). I just want an unlit, shadeless view.

Going back to Multitexture display mode and checking Shadeless seems to do nothing. It's just still white.

Comment: GLSL shading, with the material set to shadeless should work, when viewing it from textured view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blender Internal (Blender Render):

[image]

In addition to what you already did ((1) Textured viewport shading mode, (2) GLSL Shading in Properties Panel), go to the object's material and set it to **Shadeless**.

In Cycles:
[image]

Simply use the Material Viewport Shading mode.